# OpenLayers 2 polygon not displayed when site css is referenced in the page

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 2 to draw a polygon on the map using the following code. Its an angular app.

```js
var style_local =
{   strokeColor: "#00FF00",
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWidth: defaultStrokeWidth,
    fillColor: "#00FF00",
    fillOpacity: defaultFillOpacity,
    selectedColor: "#006500"
 };

let pointList = ['-27.5311111111111', '18.2166666666667', '-21.5511111111111', '18.2155555555556', '-21.5497222222222', '13.1002777777778', '-16.8216666666667', '12.7702777777778', '-13.2761111111111', '12.7655555555556', '-13.2633333333333', '10.0522222222222', '-27.5147222222222', '10.0463888888889', '-27.5311111111111', '18.2166666666667'];

var points = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < pointList.length; i += 2) {
                console.log(pointList[i]);
                console.log(pointList[i + 1]);
                let point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(pointList[i], pointList[i + 1]);
                point.transform(this.projectionOfInput, this.projectionOfOutput);
                points.push(point);
            }
linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
let polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
       linearRing, 
       { id: 123456, 
         center: points[points.length - 1], 
         code: "TestCode", 
         description: "TestDescription" 
       }, 
       style_local);

this.featuresToLoad.push(polygonFeature);
this.kmlLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Coverage");
this.kmlLayer.addFeatures(this.featuresToLoad);
this.map.addLayer(this.kmlLayer);
```

The behaviour is when I click on a button the polygon is displayed. When using the site css file the polygon doesn't show. But without the site css the polygon shows. The site.css file is pretty huge and it is hard to see what is overriding the polygon fill style. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svg {
     max-width: unset !important;
}
```

site css was setting the svg max-width to 100%. Overriding that with an unset.